# When are Endpoint Maps for Path Space Objects Fibrations?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

**TLDR:** When an object is fibrant in a model category, the endpoint maps for a very good path space object are fibrations. When is the converse true? That is, when can we conclude that an object is fibrant by knowing its endpoint maps are fibrations?

**Details:** Let $\mathcal M$ be a category with a model structure $(\mathcal C, \mathcal W, \mathcal F)$. For an object $X$, take a very good path space object to be a factorization of the diagonal $\Delta_X:X \rightarrow X \times X$ as
$$X \xrightarrow{r} P_X \xrightarrow \epsilon X\times X$$
Where $r$ is an acyclic cofibration and $\epsilon$ is a fibration.

We think of $\epsilon$ as encoding the *endpoints* of a path in $X$. If $X$ is fibrant, you may easily verify that the projection maps $\pi_0, \pi_1: X \times X \rightarrow X$ are fibrations. It follows that $\pi_i \epsilon$ is a fibration for $i = 0,1$.

I’m curious about the converse to this. Suppose we know that $\pi_i \epsilon$ is a fibration for $i = 0,1$. Can we conclude that $X$ is fibrant? If not, are there model categories in which every object has a path space object with this property? Is this possible for, say, the standard model structure on simplicial sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not yet a good answer for arbitrary model categories, but as a partial answer I can prove for simplicial sets that if $\pi_1\varepsilon\colon P_X\to X$ is a Kan fibration, then $X$ is a Kan complex. I suspect that the same is true for Joyal fibrations and quasicategories.

So, we suppose given your setup in the Kan model structure on $\mathsf{sSet}$. We need to show that $X$ is a Kan complex, so suppose given a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^n_k @>{f}>>X\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Delta^n@>>>*
\end{CD}
$$
for $n\geq 1$ and $0\leq k\leq n$. Write $f(0)=x$. Since $\varepsilon\colon P_X\to X\times X$ is a Kan fibration, so is its fiber $\varepsilon_x\colon P_{X,x}\to X\times\{x\}\cong X$, where we wrote $P_{X,x}=P_X\times_{X\times X}(X\times\{x\})$. Note that $x$ lies in the image of $\varepsilon_x$, because the diagonal of $X\times X$ lies in the image of $\varepsilon$. Say that $\widetilde{x}\in P_{X,x}$ satisfies $\varepsilon_x(\widetilde{x})=x$. Since $0\colon *\to\Lambda^n_k$ is a trivial cofibration, we can find in the commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
*@>{\widetilde{x}}>> P_{X,x}\\
@V{0}VV @VV{\varepsilon_x}V\\
\Lambda^n_k @>{f}>>X\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Delta^n@>>>*
\end{CD}
$$
a lift in the upper square. Since the $\pi_1\varepsilon\colon P_X\to X$ is assumed to be a Kan fibration, so is its pullback along $x\colon *\to X$. This means that the right vertical composite $P_{X,x}\to X\to *$ in the diagram above is a Kan fibration. Via standard lifting calculus, we obtain a lift in the lower square as well, so $X$ is a Kan complex.

Comment: Thanks again, Daniël! I’m going to leave this question open for now to see if anyone else has a more general answer.

Comment: That seems like a good idea. I will also see today if I can find a more general answer.

Comment: @Joe I couldn't find anything better than this. In general, I see no way to prove that our $X$ needs to be fibrant (and I couldn't come up with a counterexample). The problem is also that $P_X$ is only defined in terms of the factorization of the diagonal. That means that there are multiple options for it, and if for one of those the maps to $X$ are fibrations, it need not hold that they are fibrations for all choices for $P_X$. I am going to stop thinking about this now (and of course needed to let you know this).

Comment: Thank you for giving it some thought! I really appreciate the help. I’ll let you know if I come up with anything.